# I can't see a mistake in my Arduino code.

Tags: c, arduino, servo

Here is my code and when I put it into the Arduino IDE it says:

> "expected primary-expression before ',' token"

I think I forgot somewhere a dot or I made a little mistake in the if class.

Thank you very much for your help.

Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define PinOut1 

Servo myservo; 
int AnalogIn=A0;
int buttonState = 0;
int integer1 = 3;
float floating1 = PI;
String string1 = "words and numbers123";
int array1[5] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
int PinIn1 = 2;
int PinOUt = 11;
int button = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PinOUt, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PinIn1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  Conditional1();
}

void Conditional1() {
  button = digitalRead(PinIn1);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalwrite(PinOut1, HIGH);
    myservo.write(60);
  } else{
    digitalwrite(PinOut1, LOW);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `#define PinOut1 ` ??? can you provide the line of the error at least?

Comment: Java does not accept `#include` nor `#define`

Comment: Coult also be that this is "C", I went to a workshop and tried a code(this code) out at home.

Comment: I fixed it: New Code

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It's not Java, it's embedded C.

Comment: @akshayk07 I just was wondering why this question was originally marked with the [Java] tag... before it was edited out.

Comment: @akshayk07 It's not even C. It's Arduino's version of C++.

Comment: @gre_gor I said embedded C, not C   -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 4 it says 
`#define PinOut1`
try adding a space to make it
`#define PinOut 1`

EDIT:
There were also a few other things I noticed after this post so I compiled a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define PinOut1 11
Servo myservo; 
int AnalogIn=A0;
int buttonState = 0;
int integer1 = 3;
float floating1 = PI;
String string1 = "words and numbers123";
int array1[5] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};


int PinIn1 = 2;
int PinOut = 11;
int button = 0;


void setup() {
  pinMode(PinOut, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PinIn1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);
}
void loop() {
Conditional1();
}

void Conditional1() {
   button = digitalRead(PinIn1);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
digitalWrite(PinOut1, HIGH);
    myservo.write(60);

  } else{
    digitalWrite(PinOut1, LOW);
    myservo.write(0);

  }
}
```

Comment: That stopped one mistake but wasn't the final one, because then it says: "PinOut1 was not declared in this scope"!

Comment: It would do: 'int PinOUt = 11;'